# WordPress How to list all child pages in groups of two

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Alright, I haven't worked with WordPress in a while, but thought I could do this.. and failed. What I'm trying to do is list all the child pages of a specified parent page, and list them in pretty little boxes 2 by 2. I managed to get the code to list all the child pages in boxes, but I'm stuck on listing them 2 by 2. Here's the code I have.

```
<?php
$args = array(
     'post_parent' => 31, 
     'post_type' => 'page',
     'posts_per_page' => 5,
     'orderby' => 'name',
     'order' => 'ASC'
     );
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<div id="container">    
<div id="left"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<div id="right"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-post-box'); ?></div>
</div><!--//special_page_box-->     

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
} else { 
the_content();
} ?>
```

This code is working fine, for what it is, but I would really like to break them into 2 by 2, with the first item floated to the left and the second item floated to the right. And I'm completely stuck. I played with some CSS tricks and managed to have the listed inline-block, but that didn't really help. So, could any of you help me on the last step of my project? I would greatly appreciate it! I didn't supply any CSS, because I don't have any set code, I'm still experimenting.

Thank you!

*EDIT* I don't think I explained it very well, sorry about that. Here is a picture of my desired look:

[Example http://kate.illstudios.com/ex.jpg](http://kate.illstudios.com/ex.jpg)

Comment: use an integer counter and the modulus operator, `$i++`, `if($i %2 == 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any coding here is needed. Just some CSS styles. It seems that you have two divs, a left and a right, for each post so in reality you want 4 divs per row. I got it working with a little nth-child action:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .container {float:left; border: solid 1px black; width: 40%; }
  .container:nth-child(2n + 1){clear: left; margin-right: 10%;}
  .left { width: 50%; float: left; }
  .right { width: 50%; float: left;}
  .right img{width:90%; margin:0px auto; padding: 10px 0px;} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<div class="container">    
    <div class="left"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br><?php  the_content(); ?></div>
    <div class="right"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-post-box'); ?></div>
</div><!--//special_page_box-->
```

I put the width and border so it is easier to see what is happening and where the boundaries of the elements are. It would be better to select the child divs by a common class though as this code will select ALL divs under the container.

Comment: I don't think I explained it very well. That's my bad, sorry. The container is actually the whole "box". The two divs inside the container are within the one box. I wanted to list two boxes on one line, one floated left and one floated right (or neither one floated, but with a margin between them and the entire thing centered, either will be fine). I'll edit my question and include a simple picture.

Comment: Notice that I changed the IDs to class since you have them repeating.

Comment: The code you provided seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! At least the code as is does what I'm asking for! Let me see if I can work it out within WordPress, but I suspect I've found my answer. Thank you!